# Putnam 2009 A1 Points in a plane

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, contest-math

**HINTS PLEASE!**

> Let $f$ be a real-valued function on the plane such that for
>   every square $ABCD$ in the plane, $f(A)+ f(B)+ f(C)+
> f(D) = 0$. Does it follow that $f(P) = 0$ for all points $P$
>   in the plane?

**I want to try a proof by contradiction.**

Since it is square $ABCD$, it should follow WLOG, $A = B$ and $C = D$. WLOG, $f(B) > f(A)$ and $f(C) > f(D)$.

So assuming $f(P) > 0$.

$$f(P) + f(P) + f(P) + f(P) > 0$$

But then I get lost?

Comment: $A\neq B$ since they are distinct points.  $A=(x_A, y_A)$ and $B=(x_B, y_B)$.  You could assume that either $x_{A}=x_{B}$ (same x-coord) or that $y_{A}=y_{B}$ (same y-coord).

Comment: A more direct way to prove might be to choose any point $P$ and let it be the center of a square $ABCD$.

Comment: Hint expanding on the above comment: You might add 4 small squares with your test point in the middle, and then go round all the small squares. The middle point occurs in all 4 tours around the small squares, which is different from the other points. Some corners occur only one and are also located in a square.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

Edited Answer :
Let $O$ be an arbitrary point on the plane.
$f(A)+f(p)+f(O)+f(S)+$
$f(p)+f(O)+f(B)+f(q)+$
$f(O)+f(q)+f(C)+f(r)+$
$f(O)+f(s)+f(r)+f(D)=0$
This can be rearranged as 
$4f(O)+$
$f(A)+f(B)+f(C)+f(D)+$
$2(f(p)+f(q)+f(r)+f(s))$
$=4f(O)=0$.

Comment: +1 nice answer, but a proof by contradiction is not needed. Just use your diagram and equations to show that $f(O)=0$ for any point $O$, since such a square exists around any point.

Comment: Yeah, good answer. But this isnt a proof by contradiction because you never used that $f(O) \ne 0$.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Yes. I get it now. Contradiction is not required. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Amad27 As pointed out by Rory I think we can directly conclude it without contradiction. Thanks for pointing out.